# Best String matching algorithm and implementation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, algorithm, string-matching

I have this two string `string1` and `string2`. What are my best option to check if `string2` is present in `string1`. How do I implement in Ruby. Currently I am using `Regex` match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
1.9.3p194 :016 > Benchmark.measure{ 1_000_000.times{ 'asd'['a'] } }
 =>   0.430000   0.000000   0.430000 (  0.431638)

1.9.3p194 :017 > Benchmark.measure{ 1_000_000.times{ 'asd' =~ /a/ } }
 =>   0.420000   0.000000   0.420000 (  0.415391)

1.9.3p194 :018 > Benchmark.measure{ 1_000_000.times{ 'asd'.include? 'a' } }
 =>   0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.343843)
```

Surprisingly, `count('a') > 0` is giving me good results:

```
1.9.3p194 :031 >   Benchmark.measure{ 10_000_000.times{ 'asd'.count('a') > 0 } }
 =>   3.100000   0.000000   3.100000 (  3.099447)

1.9.3p194 :032 > Benchmark.measure{ 10_000_000.times{ 'asd'.include?('a') } }
 =>   3.220000   0.000000   3.220000 (  3.226521)
```

But:

```
# count('a') > 0
1.9.3p194 :056 >   Benchmark.measure{ 10_000_000.times{ 'asdrsguoing93hafehbsefu3nr3wrbibaefiafb3uwfniw4ufnsbei'.count('a') > 0 } }
 =>   3.630000   0.000000   3.630000 (  3.633329)
# include?('a')
1.9.3p194 :057 > Benchmark.measure{ 10_000_000.times{ 'asdrsguoing93hafehbsefu3nr3wrbibaefiafb3uwfniw4ufnsbei'.include?('a') } }
 =>   3.220000   0.000000   3.220000 (  3.224986)
# =~ /a/
1.9.3p194 :058 > Benchmark.measure{ 10_000_000.times{ 'asdrsguoing93hafehbsefu3nr3wrbibaefiafb3uwfniw4ufnsbei' =~ /a/ } }
 =>   3.040000   0.000000   3.040000 (  3.043130)
```

So: talking strictly about performance, you should do a test considering the distribution of your strings (which rarely is random). Talking about expressivity, maybe `include?` is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string1.include? string2
```

That should do the job

Comment: but is that the best possible way out there to do this thing?

Comment: what do you mean by 'best'? Minimum code, fastest, least memory consumption, most reliable/robust...